# Jmeter Parametrization

Tags: jmeter, text-files

I'm very new to Jmeter. I need help with the input data file for jmeter.
Here is my situation.
My test data file structure is like this:

```
Test Case Name = XXXXXX11
RequestData =  AAAAAAAAAA11
Expected Result = BBBBBBBBB11
Test Case Name = XXXXXX22
RequestData =  AAAAAAAAAA22
Expected Result = BBBBBBBBB22
and so on ....
```

Now, I have to send the http request and verify the expected using Jmeter (Maven & Continuous Integration).

How can I parse the given file and verify the expected result?

I have tried the following:

- __StringFromFile - but i don't know how to look for the line which has Request data or Expected result;
- userParameter - but not sure how to pass values on runtime.

Could any of you please help me?

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have single test-case per file (i.e. single appearance of "Test Case Name",...,etc. in file)?

If so then you can possibly try to use custom [Variables From CSV File](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/VariablesFromCSV) plugin from [Jmeter Plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) project.

Comment: Really very Thanks for looking into. However my text file has no.of test cases in it. Is there a way I could find the line which starts with "Test Case Name" in the text file ?

Comment: You can, e.g., write your own parser on java/beanshell and use it from [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) / [PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) / [PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor). But these all is quite far from jmeter's built-in functionality.

Comment: As in my humble opinion much more better solutions are either 1. use separate file per each test-case description: so each entry will be unique in file, you can use Variables From CSV File plugins and process all the files-testcases in loop; or 2. use single file for all test-cases but change it's format to csv, e.g. "TestCaseNameValue,RequestDataValue,ExpectedResultValue" per string - so you can use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) under While Controller, to read and extract all the entries till the EOF.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to convert your file to csv (with any delimiter you like). The first row becomes your heading, and each additional row becomes your data you want to pass in or validate. For example:

```
Test Case Name|Request Data|Expected Result
XXXXXX11|AAAAAAAAAA11|BBBBBBBBB11
XXXXXX22|AAAAAAAAAA22|BBBBBBBBB22
```

You can load this data in to your test plan using the CSV Data Set Config. Once you do, you'll be able to loop through each row of data if you set your Thread Group to Loop Forever. Then all you need to do in the test case is refer to your variables from the csv file like so:
`${Test Case Name}`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  so much guys! 
I just wrote a bean shell script to parse the CSV file and stored all the request & response in the array and then created a for each loop around my http sampler. That met my requirement.

```
    Thread Group
      Beanshell preprocessr (To parse my CSV and to store it in an array)
      For each loop (loops thru the array)
        http sample
        response assertion
        Results
```

Comment: I am not sure it's the best solution as it moad in memory much data , which will increase with your tests cases increasing. It also recodes a behaviour native to jmeter (csv parsing). Another point , shouldn't you reward by some votes answers which led you to this solution.